# Merge dataframes on matching A, B and *closest* C?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes like so:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- cbind(expand.grid(x=1:3, y=1:5), time=round(runif(15)*30))
to.merge <- data.frame(x=c(2, 2, 2, 3, 2),
                       y=c(1, 1, 1, 5, 4),
                       time=c(17, 12, 11.6, 22.5, 2),
                       val=letters[1:5],
                       stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I want to merge `to.merge` into `df` (with `all.x=T`) such that:

- `df$x == to.merge$x` AND
- `df$y == to.merge$y` AND
- `abs(df$time - to.merge$time) <= 1`; in the case of multiple `to.merge` that satisfy, we pick the one that minimises this distances.

**How can I do this?**

So my desired result is (this is just `df` with the corresponding `value` column of `to.merge` added for matching rows):

```
   x y time val
1  1 1    8  NA
2  2 1   11   c
3  3 1   17  NA
4  1 2   27  NA
5  2 2    6  NA
6  3 2   27  NA
7  1 3   28  NA
8  2 3   20  NA
9  3 3   19  NA
10 1 4    2  NA
11 2 4    6  NA
12 3 4    5  NA
13 1 5   21  NA
14 2 5   12  NA
15 3 5   23   d
```

where `to.merge` was:

```
  x y time val
1 2 1 17.0   a
2 2 1 12.0   b
3 2 1 11.6   c
4 3 5 22.5   d
5 2 4  2.0   e
```

Note - (2, 1, 17, a) didn't match into `df` because the `time` 17 was more than 1 away from `df$time` 11 for (X, Y) = (2, 1).

Also, there were two rows in `to.merge` that satisfied the condition for matching to `df`'s (2, 1, 11) row, but the 'c' row was picked instead of the 'b' row because its `time` was the closest to 11.

Finally, there may be rows in `to.merge` that do not match anything in `df`.

---

One way that works is a for-loop, but it takes far too long for my data (`df` has ~12k rows and `to.merge` has ~250k rows)

```
df$value <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    row <- df[i, ]
    idx <- which(row$x == to.merge$x &
                 row$y == to.merge$y &
                 abs(row$time - to.merge$time) <= 1)
    if (length(idx)) {
        j <- idx[which.min(row$time - to.merge$time[idx])]
        df$val[i] <- to.merge$val[j]
    }
}
```

I feel that I can somehow do a merge, like:

```
to.merge$closest_time_in_df <- sapply(to.merge$time,
                                  function (tm) {
                                     dts <- abs(tm - df$time)
                                     # difference must be at most 1
                                     if (min(dts) <= 1) {
                                         df$time[which.min(dts)]
                                     } else {
                                         NA
                                     }
                                  })
merge(df, to.merge,
      by.x=c('x', 'y', 'time'),
      by.y=c('x', 'y', 'closest_time_in_df'),
      all.x=T)
```

But this doesn't merge the `(2, 1, 11)` row because `to.merge$closest_time_in_df` for `(2, 1, 11.5, c)` is 12, but a time of 12 in `df` corresponds to (x, y) = (2, 5) not (2, 1) hence the merge fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `merge` couple of times and `aggregate` once, here is how to do it.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- cbind(expand.grid(x = 1:3, y = 1:5), time = round(runif(15) * 30))
to.merge <- data.frame(x = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 2), y = c(1, 1, 1, 5, 4), time = c(17, 12, 11.6, 22.5, 2), val = letters[1:5], stringsAsFactors = F)

#Find rows that match by x and y
res <- merge(to.merge, df, by = c("x", "y"), all.x = TRUE)
res$dif <- abs(res$time.x - res$time.y)
res
##   x y time.x val time.y dif
## 1 2 1   17.0   a     11 6.0
## 2 2 1   12.0   b     11 1.0
## 3 2 1   11.6   c     11 0.6
## 4 2 4    2.0   e      6 4.0
## 5 3 5   22.5   d     23 0.5

#Find rows that need to be merged
res1 <- merge(aggregate(dif ~ x + y, data = res, FUN = min), res)
res1
##   x y dif time.x val time.y
## 1 2 1 0.6   11.6   c     11
## 2 2 4 4.0    2.0   e      6
## 3 3 5 0.5   22.5   d     23

#Finally merge the result back into df
final <- merge(df, res1[res1$dif <= 1, c("x", "y", "val")], all.x = TRUE)
final
##    x y time  val
## 1  1 1    8 <NA>
## 2  1 2   27 <NA>
## 3  1 3   28 <NA>
## 4  1 4    2 <NA>
## 5  1 5   21 <NA>
## 6  2 1   11    c
## 7  2 2    6 <NA>
## 8  2 3   20 <NA>
## 9  2 4    6 <NA>
## 10 2 5   12 <NA>
## 11 3 1   17 <NA>
## 12 3 2   27 <NA>
## 13 3 3   19 <NA>
## 14 3 4    5 <NA>
## 15 3 5   23    d
```

Comment: Your row 9 shouldn't be there, because the time in `df` is 6 and the time in `to.merge` is 2, and these differ by more than 1

Comment: thankyou! very clever using the multiple `merge`, and I've never used `aggregate` before. Also, the `all.x` is not necessary your first `merge` I believe.

Answer (score 16):

Use `data.table` and `roll='nearest'` or to limit to 1, `roll = 1, rollends = c(TRUE,TRUE)`

eg

```
library(data.table)
# create data.tables with the same key columns (x, y, time)
DT <- data.table(df, key = names(df))
tm <- data.table(to.merge, key = key(DT))

# use join syntax with roll = 'nearest'


tm[DT, roll='nearest']

#     x y time val
#  1: 1 1    8  NA
#  2: 1 2   27  NA
#  3: 1 3   28  NA
#  4: 1 4    2  NA
#  5: 1 5   21  NA
#  6: 2 1   11   c
#  7: 2 2    6  NA
#  8: 2 3   20  NA
#  9: 2 4    6   e
# 10: 2 5   12  NA
# 11: 3 1   17  NA
# 12: 3 2   27  NA
# 13: 3 3   19  NA
# 14: 3 4    5  NA
# 15: 3 5   23   d
```

You can limit your self to looking forward and back (1) by setting `roll=-1` and `rollends = c(TRUE,TRUE)`

```
new <- tm[DT, roll=-1, rollends  =c(TRUE,TRUE)]
new
    x y time val
 1: 1 1    8  NA
 2: 1 2   27  NA
 3: 1 3   28  NA
 4: 1 4    2  NA
 5: 1 5   21  NA
 6: 2 1   11   c
 7: 2 2    6  NA
 8: 2 3   20  NA
 9: 2 4    6  NA
10: 2 5   12  NA
11: 3 1   17  NA
12: 3 2   27  NA
13: 3 3   19  NA
14: 3 4    5  NA
15: 3 5   23   d
```

Or you can roll=1 first, then roll=-1, then combine the results (tidying up the val.1 column from the second rolling join)

```
new <- tm[DT, roll = 1][tm[DT,roll=-1]][is.na(val), val := ifelse(is.na(val.1),val,val.1)][,val.1 := NULL]
new
    x y time val
 1: 1 1    8  NA
 2: 1 2   27  NA
 3: 1 3   28  NA
 4: 1 4    2  NA
 5: 1 5   21  NA
 6: 2 1   11   c
 7: 2 2    6  NA
 8: 2 3   20  NA
 9: 2 4    6  NA
10: 2 5   12  NA
11: 3 1   17  NA
12: 3 2   27  NA
13: 3 3   19  NA
14: 3 4    5  NA
15: 3 5   23   d
```

Comment: Is your input data different? Your output is not matching with OP's desired output.

Comment: Your input data appears different to mine. However I tried with my input data, and your solution still merges `DT`'s (2, 4, 6) row with `tm`'s (2, 4, 2) row, which it shouldn't, because the difference in times here is more than 1 (as stated in the question)

Comment: @geektrader. Good catch. I hadn't run `set.seed(1)`. I've also now included the actual answer to his question (:blush:)

Comment: Thanks, slick answer! I accepted geektrader's purely because I don't have to use `data.table` for it (which confuses me mightily), but I may eventually transition to `data.table` so I'll keep this in mind!

Comment: Just a comment - I've been playing with this a bit and have noticed that for my actual data, `roll=1` will only merge some rows, and `roll=-1` will merge some others, and only if I combine the two will I get all that I expect to be merged. (and I can't seem to reproduce it in my particular toy dataset for the question, so I'm not sure what causes it). Does this ring a bell with you as to why it would be happening?

Comment: It does, I had a long convaluted approach rolling -1, then 1 and then replacing NA values appropriately, but thought the rollends solution was identical. hmmm

Comment: OK, I have worked out how to reproduce. `to.merge <- rbind(to.merge, list(x=2, y=1, time=9.5, val='f'))` and contrast rolling with 1 and -1. It occurs (say for `roll=1`) when you have an invalid value before (as 9.5 is < 11 but differs by more than 1) and a valid value after (the 11.6). `roll=1` seems to notice that the before row is invalid so it puts `NA`, not even checking the after row. Would you mind putting up your convoluted approach again? (the data.table solution is way way way faster than the `merge` one, though I have spent much longer trying to understand it)

Comment: @mathematical.coffee -- i've added it, and replaced roll=1 with roll=-1 in the original solution (as =1 did not appear to work (as you noticed). `-1` seems more robust, but I don't know why!

Comment: @mnel cheers! (you can get the same problem rolling with -1 if you have a valid value before and an invalid after - I think the only fully robust solution is to roll with +1 and -1 and merge the NAs as you did)

Comment: perhaps update/"modernize" this with the `on` argument?

Answer (score 1):

[mnel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16095985/3817004) uses `roll = "nearest"` in a `data.table` join but does not limit to +/- 1 as requested by the OP. In addition, [MichaelChirico has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095680/merge-dataframes-on-matching-a-b-and-closest-c#comment64251902_16095985) to use the `on` parameter.

This approach uses

- `roll = "nearest"`,
- an update *by reference*, i.e., without copying,
- `setDT()` to coerce a data.frame to `data.table` without copying (introduced 2014-02-27 with v.1.9.2 of `data.table`),
- the `on` parameter which spares to set a key explicitely (introduced 2015-09-19 with v.1.9.6).

So, the code below

```
library(data.table)   # version 1.11.4 used
setDT(df)[setDT(to.merge), on  = .(x, y, time), roll = "nearest",
          val := replace(val, abs(x.time - i.time) > 1, NA)]
df
```

has updated `df`:

> ```
>     x y time  val
>  1: 1 1    8 <NA>
>  2: 2 1   11    c
>  3: 3 1   17 <NA>
>  4: 1 2   27 <NA>
>  5: 2 2    6 <NA>
>  6: 3 2   27 <NA>
>  7: 1 3   28 <NA>
>  8: 2 3   20 <NA>
>  9: 3 3   19 <NA>
> 10: 1 4    2 <NA>
> 11: 2 4    6 <NA>
> 12: 3 4    5 <NA>
> 13: 1 5   21 <NA>
> 14: 2 5   12 <NA>
> 15: 3 5   23    d
> ```

Note that the order of rows has not been changed (in contrast to [Chinmay Patil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16096226/3817004))

In case `df` must not be changed, a new data.table can be created by

```
result <- setDT(to.merge)[setDT(df), on  = .(x, y, time), roll = "nearest",
                .(x, y, time, val = replace(val, abs(x.time - i.time) > 1, NA))]
result
```

which returns the same result as above.